# Is there a special name for numbers whose multiples remain multiples when reversed?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I recently noticed that reversing multiples of 11 gives you other multiples of 11, for example

11 x 19 = 209 & 902 ÷ 11 = 82

...is there a name for that?
&, 
if so, 
does that same name apply to multiples of 3 & 9, whose reversed multiples are also multiples of 3 & 9 (respectively)?

I googled "patterns in 11 times table" & "reversible multiples", etc etc, but found no info on this 'anomoly'.

Answer (score 3):

Any multiple of $11$ will again be a multiple when reversed.  That is a consequence of the [divisibility rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for $11$.  You sum the digits in odd places and subtract the sum of the digits in even places.  If the difference is a multiple of $11$, so is the original number.  Reversing a number with an odd number of digits leaves the numbers in places of the same parity.  Reversing a number with an even number of digits swaps the digits in even and odd places.  In either case a difference that is a multiple of $11$ is maintained.

Similarly for multiples of $3$ or $9$.  Here the rule is that the sum of all the digits has to be a multiple of $3$ or $9$ and swapping the number does not change the sum.

In other bases $b$, multiples of $b+1, b-1$ and their factors will have the same behavior.

I am not aware of any name for these.

Comment: if i could find an explanation of the divisibilty rule that i could actually understand (it's not exactly dyslexic friendly) i'm sure it would only serve to confirm what i said about the number eleven...but not explain it :(